# Apache Cordova Local Notification plugin icon

Tags: cordova, localnotification

Has anyone use the [local notification plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/)?

I'm trying to build an app for Android that shows notification with icon from picture taken by user's camera. However I can't get the 'icon' to  work. I tried to use **.bmp** file and external file on the web (to test just in case there was an issue with it reading my file system), but no luck.

The codes are quite straight forward, I could get the notification works but not the icon. Below are my codes:

```
. . .
for (i = 0; i < _notificationDates.length; i++) {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
        id: _notificationKey + _model.id + "_" + i,
        date: _notificationDates[i],
        message: 'Reminder to take ' + _model.name + '. ' + _model.description,
        icon: _model.fileURI // have tried using external (http://...) .bmp or .jpg file does not work as well
        //,smallIcon: _model.fileURI
    });
}
. . .
```

_model.fileURI points to an image stored internally, however I have tried external URI as well (e.g.; http:// . . .) that points to .bmp or .jpg image

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hi VeldMuijz, I have added the codes. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem - I added a 24px PNG Icon via a web URL, but Android just shows the standard bell icon

Comment: me too , i have the some probleme , ur u found the solution please :'(

Answer (score 1):

A late answer. I had this problem too. It was very annoying to have to run it again and again on my device just to find the right uri. After a while it seemed it only worked when the icons where in platforms/android/res/drawable.
I eventually created a after_build_hook. It's on [Github](https://github.com/rienk-git/cordova-plugin-local-notifications-drawable-creator)

Cheers.

Edit: Ok, the essentials:

On cordova build the platforms/android/res/drawable-xxx folders are automagically created when you have things like

```
 <icon src="res/android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
```

in your config.xml. 
However, the default folder for icons for cordova-plugin-local-notifications is platforms/android/res/drawable. I could not find a way to create a default folder like this. So I created an after_build_hook.

code:

```
 var fs = require('fs-extra');
// rootdir
var rootDir = process.cwd();

//emptyDir creates dir when not present
fs.emptyDir(rootDir+'/platforms/android/res/drawable', function (err)    {

 //simple task, just nest it

  fs.copy(rootDir + '/res/android/drawable', rootDir +'/platforms/android/res/drawable', function (err) {

if (err) console.log(err)
if (!err) process.stdout.write('created drawable folder')


});

})
```

This copies your notification icons from yourproject/res/drawable to yourproject/platforms/android/res/android/drawable

Run it as a hook. In your config.xml:

```
<hook type="after_build" src="scripts/aboveCodeblock.js"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for -1!  Very consistent! Do not give anyone a chance to edit an answer!

Comment: FYI: I wasn't the one who downvoted you. However, I just upvoted you because your answer looks excellent after the edit.

Comment: Ok no problem, that thanks is meant for the other guy :)

Comment: Thanks user3791775 , I couldn't remember how I overcame this issue. . It was long time ago...  However thank you for answering this and hopefully useful for those who are still having this issue..

Btw, I didn't downvoted you

Comment: Thanks, just trying to save others some time... Like others on stackOverflow have saved me some...